# What is the preferred way of allocating C++ class member data?

Tags: c++, memory-management

Let's say I have a class that allocates some arbitrary member data. There are two common ways that I have seen used (I know that there are others):

```
class A
{
    public:
        A();
        ~A();

        //Accessors...
    private:
        B *mB;
}

A::A()
{
    mB = new B();
}

A::~A()
{
    delete B;
}
```

Versus...

```
class A
{
    public:
        //Accessors...
    private:
        B mB;
}
```

Assume that A itself will be allocated on the heap by consumer code.

In the general case, which method is preferred? I realize that specific situations really encourage one way or the other, but in absence of those demands, is one way preferred? What are the tradeoffs?

Comment: can't answer that question unless it is known if 'B' is also likely to depend on 'A' or not.

Comment: funny things happen with pointers in default copy/assignment . :-X

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The second is the preferred route.  Do not use new / delete unless you specifically need a variable to be on the heap or have a lifetime longer than it's container.  C++ value types are easier to manage and have less error cases to worry about IMHO

Answer (score 4):

**It depends.**

In general, If a B is large and unwieldy then it's easier to pass around a pointer to the B than the B itself. So if the B will often be disassociated from the A (f'rinstance if your A's swap B's) then the first way is better.

Using a pointer can also reduce dependencies. If you do it right, `A.hh` can get by without specifiying what a B is or does (i.e. `A.h` need not `#include "B.hh"`) so that things that depend on `A.hh` won't necessarily depend on `B.hh`.

The price of using pointers is an extra layer of machinery and the dangers of things like lost objects, double-deletion and the dereferencing of uninitialized pointers, so it shouldn't be used unless it actually gives a benefit in your situation. Some people fall in love with pointer techniques and use them everywhere; if they want to improve as programmers they have to grow out of it.

Answer (score 0):

In general, prefer direct composition (the second choice). In that case there is no chance of leaking memory and the object is fully located in a contiguous memory block, allowing better cache locality.

You might use the first option if you're implementing a PIMPL, or you have a need to use one of several possible class types (via inheritance). In that case definitely use a smart pointer (`boost::shared_ptr` for example) to manage the memory for you.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, mainly, on what you are looking for.

For **simplicity's sake**: don't use a pointer. Therefore the second choice.

It's easier to manage (no need to worry about memory management, deep copying, deep constness, etc...).

However you might need dynamically allocated attributes sometimes:

- if you need polymorphism (otherwise you have a truncation)
- if you want to cut down your dependencies (in the header file) --> see [PIMPL here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597693/how-does-the-pimpl-idiom-reduce-dependencies/3599001#3599001)

Even in this case though, hand over the responsibility to a smart manager (smart pointer, dedicated pimpl class, etc...)