# CMake - Different Include Directories For Different Targets?

Tags: c++, linux, cmake

I'm developing a C++ project in Linux using CMake.

I am creating two libraries, `LibA` and `LibB`. I do not want `LibA` and `LibB` to have the same include directories. Is there any way I can set only `LibA` to include `DirectoryA` and set only `LibB` to include `DirectoryB`?

Edit:

Both `LibA` and `LibB` will be used in an executable, `MyExe`. When I `#include` `LibA.h` and `LibB.h` in MyExe's source code, I cannot have the included header files from `DirectoryA` and `DirectoryB`coexisting in `MyExe`, as this will create namespace conflicts.

Is this possible?

Edit 2 : Here is my CMakeLists.txt
include_directories(include)

```
add_library(LibA src/LibA.cpp include/LibA.h)
set_property(TARGET LibA PROPERTY INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES /opt/SomeLibrary2.0/include/)
target_link_libraries(LibA /opt/SomeLibrary2.0/lib/a.so /opt/SomeLibrary2.0/lib/b.so /opt/SomeLibrary2.0/lib/c.so)

add_library(LibB src/LibB.cpp include/LibB.h)
set_property(TARGET LibB PROPERTY INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${LIB_B_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(LibB ${LIB_B_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(MyExe src/myexe.cpp)
target_link_libraries(MyExe LibA LibB)
```

But I'm still getting errors. LibA.h says that SomeLibrary's header files cannot be found?

Comment: Split the CMake files, make them subdirectories.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. My original question was updated to better reflect my issue.

Comment: `I cannot have the included header files from DirectoryA and DirectoryB coexisting in MyExe, as this will create namespace conflicts` IMHO it is design issue, if you solve include conflicts you may have strange linker errors and unexpected runtime behaviour

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you can specify CMake version 2.8.12 as the minimum, you can use [`target_include_directories`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/command/target_include_directories.html).  This was introduced in version 2.8.11, but I think it was a bit buggy until 2.8.12.

So you can do:

```
target_include_directories(LibA PRIVATE DirectoryA)
target_include_directories(LibB PRIVATE DirectoryB)
```

If you have to support older versions of CMake, you can set the [`INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/prop_tgt/INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.html) property on the targets appropriately:

```
set_property(TARGET LibA
             PROPERTY INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/DirectoryA)
set_property(TARGET LibB
             PROPERTY INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/DirectoryB)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My original question was updated to better reflect my issue.

Comment: I'm currently using 2.8.7, so not as of now. If 2.8.12 has features which will solve my problem then I will update CMake.

Comment: I updated my answer to show libs rather than exes.  There should be no need to upgrade CMake - using either method should not cause the include directories of the libraries to become include dirs of the exe.

Comment: So I unwittingly installed the one of the libraries "DirectoryA" to my /usr/local/ directory, so the entire project already sees it. I'm reinstalling the library to /opt/DirectoryA/ and giving this a shot. Rebuilding this library could be process however.

Comment: I think this is now a design issue.  I'm guessing that `LibA` builds OK on its own, but when you try to build `MyExe` the failure happens.  If `LibA.h` includes a header from `/opt/SomeLibrary2.0/include/` (directly or indirectly via one of its other include files), and `MyExe` includes `LibA.h`, then `/opt/SomeLibrary2.0/include/` *must* be available as a search path for `MyExe` too.  Off the top of my head, you can maybe consider using the [pimpl idiom](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3597693/2556117) to avoid having to expose `SomeLibrary2.0`'s headers to `MyExe`.