# Static library that depends on other static libraries

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, static-libraries, header-files

I am writting a game, and at the same time building an engine for it and for other games I may make in the future. During testing on both the game logic and the engine (separately) run well. However when I try to link them together, I encountered some problem with the inclusion of header files.

To be specific, here is what I did:

The engine is built as Static Library (.lib), and depends on GLFW static library (glfw3.lib). It contains a Window.h file:

```
// Window.h
#pragma once
#include <glfw3.h> // include other library's header

#include <iostream>
//test if the linking success
void test() {
    std::cout << "this is Window.h";
}    

class Window
{
    // Window class code (declaration, function prototype, etc...)
}
```

*Note that the location of GLFW library is separated from engine/game project location.

The game project is hosted under the same Solution with the engine project. In the game's Properties, I have add the engine as dependencies as well as engine's .lib and include location. Then I try the following:

```
// game's main file
#include <Window.h> 

void main()
{
    test(); // call the test function from Window.h
}
```

When building the game, I got an error says that it can not find such file called "glfw3.h". However, if I comment out the inclusion of glfw3.h in Window.h file:

```
# Window.h
#pragma once
//#include <glfw3.h>
```

then the game build and run normally, and prints out the test line in test function.

I want to build the engine as a single .lib with header files that prototypes functions for its classes; so that in the game project I only need to include/depend the engine library and no need to care about GLFW or such. How can I achive that?
I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39812086/), but it seems the answers don't solve my question.

Comment: Have you added the path to the folder containing glew.h to the project's "Additional Include Directories" property?

Comment: In Engine's project, I've added the path to glew.h in both "Include Directories" and "Additional Include Directories".
In Game's project, I don't add anything related to GLEW or sort, since my goal is to make game depends only on engine itself.

Comment: Why does Window.h include glew.h? What in Window.h depends upon it?

Comment: I'm sorry, not glew.h but actually glfw3.h (I just include glew.h temporarily for testing). Original question edited.
This time I have added the path to glfw3.h in "Additional Include Directories" as absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the suggestion from the related post below. Basically build your library as you are doing then statically merge it with the glfw static lib.

[How to merge two windows vc static library into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13492365/how-to-merge-two-windows-vc-static-library-into-one)